# NSSearchField delegate in Yosemite

Tags: swift3, nssearchfield

I'm making a new Swift (3.0) framenwork which involves the use of a NSSearchField programmatically created, like the rest of the views.
This framenwork has the deployment target set to 10.10 and I found strange being not able to set the delegate metods for it. In fact NSSearchFieldDelegate only appear availabe in 10.11 on.

```
class PlistEditor: NSObject, NSOutlineViewDelegate, NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSTextFieldDelegate, NSSearchFieldDelegate {
 var searchField : NSSearchField?
 // more code..
 init(tabItem: NSTabViewItem,
       plistPath: String?) {
        // more code..
        let sf = NSSearchField(frame: NSMakeRect(80, 0, 80, 22))
        self.searchField? = sf
        // more code..
        super.init()
        // more code..
        if #available(OSX 10.11, *) {
            self.searchField?.delegate = self
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions

        }

        // more code
    }
```

}

Ok, I thought it was inherent from NStextField, and maybe I can access the cell and set up using the superclass delegate, but unfurtunately I cannot found a way to do that. 
What I need is to be able to receive NSText/NSTextField notification in 10.10. How can I do this? 
[image: error received]

[image: plist editor vibrant]

EDITED:
added more info on how is made plus some picts

Comment: what is the error u are receiving?

Comment: Added more info and picts, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without providing more info, i am guessing you forgot to declare that your class is conforming to the `NSSearchFieldDelegate`.

See the example below, how to set it up for example a viewController. You just create an extension for your vc, and declare it to conform to the delegate.

```
class SearchViewController: NSViewController {
    let searchField: NSSearchField? = NSSearchField(frame: .zero)

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        if #available(OSX 10.11, *) {
            self.searchField?.delegate = self
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions

        }
    }
}

extension SearchViewController: NSSearchFieldDelegate {
    func searchFieldDidStartSearching(_ sender: NSSearchField) {
        print("didStart")
    }

    func searchFieldDidEndSearching(_ sender: NSSearchField) {
        print("didEnd")
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
To capture the `textDidChange` event in earlier versions of Mac OS, you need to subclass `NSSearchField` and override `textDidChange` function. Every time a change happens in the searchField, it will call the function for you.

```
class DLSearchField: NSSearchField {

    override func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        Swift.print("textDidChange")
    }
}
```

Comment: Added more info, but as I said the deployment target is 10.10. You think it should work anyway? Thanks

Comment: You just need to add the `if.#available(OSX 10.11, *)` check before you would assign the delegate. It should work for anything higher than `10.11`.

Comment: Yes, it's already working well in 10.11 and Sierra. I think I need to reach the NSTextFieldCell somehow and set the classic NSTextFieldDelegate that for me should be enough. If possible. The pity is that in IB work as expected but here everything is in code..

Comment: the two delegate is very different. What would you like to observe?

Comment: Only the "Text Did Change", for everything else I have my own methods to tell the outlineview how behave.

Comment: Accepted! It works. I'll setup the existing code to use this subclass only in Yosemite, and preserve the original behavior of the search field in newer OS. Thanks!